# Invoking mpirun inside "while read" loop, only first line is processed

Tags: bash, openmpi

I need to run several tasks in sequence. The task names are listed in a file (jobs.txt). I use the following code (example):

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS=$'\r' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
done < "jobs.txt"
```

It works well. However, I need to run these tasks with openmpi (in this example, change `echo $line` to `mpirun -n 4 echo $line`), then the script does not work any more... It only read the first line from "jobs.txt" and stopped.

Any idea what's the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: does `mpirun` consume `stdin`?  It might be draining the rest of `jobs.txt` if so

Comment: shouldn't the nonzero test be inside the loop?  `while READ; do NONZERO && ECHO; done <FILE`;  I don't see how `READ or NONZERO` is different from `READ`

Comment: Add `</dev/null` on the `mpirun` line, and see [BashFAQ #89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Comment: @jhnc, the purpose of `read -r line || [[ $line ]]` as an idiom is to proceed into the body of the loop when the last line of the file doesn't have a terminating newline. `read` returns a nonzero exit status but still populates its output variable in that case. Of course, better practice is to generate valid UNIX text files, in which *all* lines have terminating newlines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, haven't encountered that before

Comment: Since you are using Open MPI, an other option is to `mpirun --stdin none -n 4 echo $line`. Keep in mind the **same** line will be printed 4 times (an other way to put it is that if you expect 4 MPI tasks print 4 different lines, you are doing it wrong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks problem solved by your instruction.